# auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password')) - Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

**

### This is my LoginController.php :

**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {

        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function loginCheck(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[

            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);


        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
            return back()->with('status','Invalid login details');
        }

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

### Login.blade.php - Design

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-4/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">

            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="bg-red-500 p-4 rounded-lg mb-6 text-white text-center">
                    {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif

            <form action="{{ route('login')}}" method="post">
                @csrf

                 <div class="mb-4">
                     <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"
                     class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg @error('email') border-red-500 @enderror" 
                     value="{{ old('email') }}">

                     @error('email')
                     <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text=sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                 </div>
 
                 <div class="mb-4">
                     <label for="password" class="sr-only">Passowrd</label>
                     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"
                     class="bg-gray-100 border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg @error('password') border-red-500 @enderror"
                      value="{{ old('password') }}">

                     @error('password')
                     <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text=sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                 </div>

 
                 <div class="mb-4">
                     <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-3 rounded font-medium w-full">Log in
                     </button>
                 </div>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

### web.php -Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');

Route::get('/posts',[RegisterController::class, 'posts'])->name('posts');

Route::get('/register',[RegisterController::class, 'registration'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register',[RegisterController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'loginCheck']);


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});
```

Even If I try to dd();
it shows me false,

auth()->user(); in dashboard shows null?

but data is getting stored in MySql Server.
but Not auth()->attemp()-> Login. why?

Here, I'm trying to store my data to the MySql Server When registering as a new user and directly logged in and redirect to the dashboard page.

Comment: don't actually know if this matters, but does `->only()` require an array?

Answer (score 0):

You code is using Laravel blade directives in the controller, rather than utilising the Auth facade provided by Laravel.

Mainly, you should add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` to the top of your controller, then switch

```
if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
            return back()->with('status','Invalid login details');
        }
```

to

```
if(!Auth::attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
            return back()->with('status','Invalid login details');
        }
```

You should then also look at adding the `auth` middleware to your Dashboard route.

Further information on manually authenticating a user in Laravel can be found at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users - Including regenerating the session and proper redirect, which you should add to your Controller.

Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

To use `auth()->user()` in the dashboard, you must protect the route to that page with the Auth middleware. If you don't, it'll keep returning null each time

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth')->name('dashboard');
```

Also, consider regenerating the session after Auth attempt. Just to be safe

```
$request->session()->regenerate()
```

I hope this helps. Happy Coding!